# How to italicize reStructuredText when something other than a space follows?

Tags: restructuredtext

I'm trying to italicize (or bold) text in reStructuredText, but after the asterisk, there is not a space. Here's an example:

```
*function_name*(args)
```

I want it to look like: *function_name*(args)

I want function_name to be italicized, but I do not want the parentheses or "args" to be italicized. The problem is that rst does not recognize the closing asterisk because there is no space after this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out, I need to use an escaped space, which will behave like space but will not show up. See [here](https://developer.lsst.io/restructuredtext/style.html#inline-text-styling).

So this works:

```
*function_name*\ (args)
```

To show up like:

*function_name*(args)